# Travis CI build error with my R package that uses C++, Rcpp and RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, travis-ci, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

Here is the GitHub repo of my [R package](https://github.com/ntthung/ldsr)

I've been able to install this package from source on Windows, MacOS, and a Linux cluster with `devtools::install_github("ntthung/ldsr")`

I'm trying to integrate Travis CI and upon build, I get the following error

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ldsr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...): unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpK7z3X6/Rinst2ef05609c709/00LOCK-ldsr/00new/ldsr/libs/ldsr.so':/tmp/RtmpK7z3X6/Rinst2ef05609c709/00LOCK-ldsr/00new/ldsr/libs/ldsr.so: undefined symbol: dpotrf_

I found that `dpotrf_` belongs to a library called `libflame`. So I made the file `Rload.R` with te command `Sys.setenv("PKG-LIBS"="-llibflame")` and added the following to `.travis.yml`

```
script:
    - Rscript Rload.R
    - R CMD build . --compact-vignettes=gs+qpdf
    - R CMD check *tar.gz --as-cran
```

But I still get the same error.

My package uses Rcpp and RcppArmadillo.

Help please! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like the basic error of not having a proper `src/Makevars` as would have been created from *e.g.* `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()` and others.

So as a first basic fix attempt, copy in the file [inst/skeleton/Makevars](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/skeleton/Makevars) from RcppArmadillo which contains

```
## With R 3.1.0 or later, you can uncomment the following line to tell R to 
## enable compilation with C++11 (where available)
##
## Also, OpenMP support in Armadillo prefers C++11 support. However, for wider
## availability of the package we do not yet enforce this here.  It is however
## recommended for client packages to set it.
##
## And with R 3.4.0, and RcppArmadillo 0.7.960.*, we turn C++11 on as OpenMP
## support within Armadillo prefers / requires it
CXX_STD = CXX11

PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) 
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

You did copy in the Windows variant `Makevars.win` you just forgot the main one.

And [`dpotrf_`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/dpotrf.f.html) is a standard LAPACK symbol so the error is an obvious one for more experienced users (and this question is likely a duplicate too). Also, looking at the sources of the 600+ other CRAN packages using RcppArmadillo is often a good idea too -- they are all on GitHub under user `cran`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dirk! When installing the package on a Linux cluster, I got a similar error, but with `dgels_`, and I was able to fix it with `Sys.setenv("PKG-LIBS"="-llapack")`, thanks to another question. But I wasn't able to do something similar here. I think adding the `Makevars` fundamentally fixed the problem. I don't know why it didn't get copied together with `Makevars.win`. Thanks again.

Comment: @Drumy: I am glad that helped but _it is still wrong_. Every RcppArmadillo package should have the three lines above, and just by copying that that `src/Makevars` in you get it automatically---without the need for your manual `Sys.setenv()`.  I would reconsider, and/or for tests start from a fresh `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton("quickTest")`.

Comment: To follow up on this, I still get the same error even with the files copied exactly. Not sure why this would be, but will perhaps make a post if I cant figure it out.